# How to export saved places from google maps to my application mobile using google maps sdk for ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Is it possible to export saved places from Google Maps to my application mobile, using Google Maps SDK for iOS or Android.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you be specific on what you are looking for? your question appears a bit challenging to even undersrtand

Answer (score -1):

I'm too working on that and i haven't found anything about how to import my saved places on google maps to my android application.